# Traversing the response text

Tags: javascript

I am using Ajax for request/response. I am getting responseText having lot of divs and hidden fields(HTML page). From this how can I get my required div id from the responseText?, I don't want to store responseText in any other div's innerHTML, instead, just I want to access my required div id from the responseText using javascript. Below is the Html content which I get in ajax response.

> testissue123
>
> ```
>     <div class="even_row" 
> style="width:49%;
> padding-right:1%;float:left;padding-bottom:3px;
> padding-top:3px;height:20px;"> 
>     <div class="label_11px" style="width:60%">
>         </div> 
>     </div> 
>
> <input typ="hidden" id="variable18" value="userClassVariable18,3,1212,1355" />
> ```

And storing the responseText in one variable, following is the same mentioned.

```
onSuccess: function(transport) {
 var response = transport.responseText; 
}
```

Comment: can you post your code

Comment: Please, post come response text sample and what you have tried so far

Comment: @AnilGoud Can you please [edit the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/28027951/edit) to include these snippets? They can be formatted as [blocks of code](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) by prefixing each line with 4 spaces.

Comment: so you dont have any code to actually do what you want?. you haven't even posted the ajax call, what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to load the responseText to a hidden div element in the page and then simply doing set x=document.getElementById("MyDiv").innerHTML; where MyDiv is the div you require. Then use x to do what you want.

Comment: Thankyou for response, but I don't wan't load responseText in any hidden field, because my requirement is like that.